Does Kamala Harris have Jamaican (in addition to US) citizenship?
It seems to me that Kamala Harris probably has both Jamaican and US citizenship. Not questioning her US citizenship or eligibility to be President of the US, I am just asking, as an interesting academic matter about a public figure, whether she has Jamaican citizenship. This is the reasoning:
Kamala Harris's father, Donald Harris, was born in Jamaica in 1938. According to the constitution of Jamaica, someone born in Jamaica before independence in 1962 automatically became a Jamaican citizen upon independence. Section 3B(1)(a) of the current revision of the constitution of Jamaica says:


Every person born in Jamaica shall become a citizen of Jamaica-

a. on the sixth day of August, 1962, in the case of a person born
before that date;

(This text has been amended. The original 1962 constitution text, section 3(1) (on page 1693 of this book), is similar:

(1) Every person who, having been born in the former Colony of
Jamaica, is on the fifth day of August 1962 a citizen of the United
Kingdom and Colonies shall become a citizen of Jamaica on the sixth
day of August 1962.

According to British law, someone born in a British colony, like Jamaica, would have automatically become a British subject at birth, and would have automatically become a Citizen of the UK and Colonies in 1949, so this would have applied to Donald Harris.)
Kamala Harris was born in the US in 1964. According to constitution of Jamaica, a child born abroad to a father who was a Jamaican citizen otherwise than by descent is automatically a Jamaican citizen at birth.  Section 3C(b) of the current revision of the constitution of Jamaica says:

Every person born outside Jamaica shall become a citizen of Jamaica-
b. on the date of his birth, in the case of a person born on or after
the sixth day of August, 1962,
if, at that date, his father or mother is a citizen of Jamaica by
birth, descent or registration by virtue of marriage to a citizen of
Jamaica.

(This text has been amended. The original 1962 constitution text, section 6 (on page 1694 of this book), is similar:


A person born outside Jamaica after the fifth day of August 1962 shall become a citizen of Jamaica at the date of his birth if at that
date his father is a citizen of Jamaica otherwise than by virtue of
this section or subsection (2) of section 3 of this Constitution.


Originally, Jamaican citizenship by descent could only be passed from the father, not the mother, and only if the father was a citizen otherwise than by descent; this doesn't make a difference for the purposes of this question, since Kamala's father was a Jamaican citizen by virtue of having been born in Jamaica.)
Here, the citizenship by descent is automatic and involuntary. The text says "shall become", not "has the option to become" or "can apply to become". The text does not require any application, registration, choice, claim, or other action for a child to be a Jamaican citizen by descent.
Section 8(2) of the original 1962 text provided that the Governor-General could issue an order to revoke the Jamaican citizenship of anyone exercising the rights of a foreign citizenship:

(2) If the Governor-General is satisfied that any citizen of Jamaica
has at any time after the fifth day of August 1962 voluntarily claimed
and exercised in a country other than Jamaica any rights available to
him under the law of that country, being rights accorded exclusively
to its citizens, the Governor-General may by order deprive that person
of his citizenship.

This provision has since been repealed and is no longer present in the current revision of the constitution. In any case, I am not aware of the Jamaican government ever having made such an order prior to the repeal of this provision, nor do I think it is likely for them to have ever done so.
It is also possible that Kamala Harris renounced Jamaican citizenship, but I am not aware of her having done so.
So given the above, is it correct to conclude that Kamala Harris currently has Jamaican citizenship (in addition to her US citizenship for having been born in the US)?
Again, I am not questioning Kamala's Harris's US citizenship, her status as a natural-born US citizen, or her legal eligibility to be President of the US. I understand that there is no legal prohibition against dual citizens being President of the US, although it might become a political issue (e.g. Ted Cruz renounced his Canadian citizenship in 2014 prior to his campaign for the Republican nomination for President, though he didn't have to).

The provisions in the Jamaican constitution seem clear. So unless her citizenship has been revoked, why wouldn't she still be a citizen?

It seems like you already provided the answer to your question.

Maybe this should be on the Politics SE.

@quarague if one does not include enough prior research, one receives the "what have you found out from your research. Then one learns to do and include evidence of good due diligence, only to receive the "you already answered your question" comments. I see a lot of information that may be useful to an answer author, but certainly not enough by itself to be conclusive. I think a proper SE answer will need to take it up another notch.

@uhoh I'm not sure what aspect you are missing. The question as such is fine but to me it seems OP already did the research needed for an answer. So maybe they could have posted it as a self-answer but I don't see what else an answer should include, the information already in the question answers OPs question for me.

@uhoh "what have you found out from your research" is not a critique you'll find here, unless a question is so simple, it isn't clear what the issue is. The more a user tries to tell us, the less they're asking a question. They often just end up introducing material that needs debunking or assumptions that are legally dubious. This site isn't a "debunk my argument" site. The best questions state just enough context or facts to assume so that the legal question makes sense. https://law.meta.stackexchange.com/q/600/46948 (points 4 and 5 seem relevant).

@Jen yes I keep forgetting this, thank you for the reminder. This is a well constructed and written SE question but ya, as Allure also mentions above, it's written like a good question for Politics SE but not here. I don't have enough reputation to vote to close but it seems like a great candidate for migration so I can at least leave a flag for that.

@uhoh, just because something is a question is a good fit on another site does not mean it's not also a fit here. Questions regarding citizenship are absolutely a legal question and while there may be a lot politics in developing the law, there is presumably a law and thus we can try to answer based on what it says.

@uhoh What makes it a good fit for Politics? They specifically said they're not asking about her presidential eligibility. There's nothing in the Constitution prohibiting dual citizens from being POTUS.

@Barmar there could be political implications.  Those would be on topic for Politics.

While I am no expert in this area, in many other cases I've read about, an eligible child would have to claim the citizenship of the other country, rather than it automatically being applied.

@phoog If you substitute "Kamala" for any other random person whose father was Jamaican (and born at the same time), would this be a Politics topic?  Yes, this particular subject has potential political implications, but IMHO the base question is purely legal.

@PeterM many countries' nationality laws have automatic effect in at least some circumstances.  Almost every citizen of the US, for example, including most of those born abroad, is automatically a citizen of the US.  It's true that someone has to assert whatever facts exist leading to this automatic citizenship, but the person making the assertion does not need to be the person whose citizenship is in question.

@PeterM indeed, the base question is purely legal.  The political implications arise because the person being asked about is a political figure.

@Barmar Substantial prior research makes it a good question for politics SE. Other things might not, but those are, as yet, untested.

@PeterM Politics SE has a "law" tag, there are legal questions there. It's not that this question is off-topic here, it's that it's long, well-researched and tries to formulate the beginnings of an answer rather than simply poses a short, concise question. "The more a user tries to tell us, the less they're asking a question." The question post as written seems unwelcome here by the community, whereas the style is a good fit in Politics.
